# Как хранить большое количество небольших файлов?

Tags: хранение-данных, storage, amazon-s3, gearman

Имеется задача: сначала скачать много мелких картинок (10-20 килобайт), потом к каждой наделать превьюшек (до 10 разных к каждой). 
Исходных картинок может быть 200-300 миллионов, соответственно всего файлов больше миллиарда.
Потом все это дело надо хранить, и выдавать по запросу разными кусками.

**Как бы лучше это организовать?**

**Что мы делали:**
Хранение предполагалось в виде файлов, с вложенными папками, исходя из md5(id), примерно так:
/aa/bb/cc/dd/34345.jpg
Скачивать и ресайзить многопоточно (воркеры Gearman).

На сервере, где файлы хранятся, все хорошо. Но другие должны как-то передать то, что скачали, серверу-хранилищу. rsync безбожно тормозит на таком количестве папок. Если заливать напрямую на хранилище после скачивания, теряется смысл кросс-серверного скачивания (нагрузка на диск на хранилище и так большая от его собственных скачиваний). Это проблема раз.
Проблема  два - не хватит inodes на файловой системе.

Рассматривали вариант хранилища в s3, но получается очень дорого платить за запросы (само место дешевое и полностью устраивает, тем более частый доступ к этим файлам не нужен).

Спасите, помогите.

Comment: Обязательно хранить превьюшки? Крупные проекты (вроде того же ютуба) держат у себя серверы, которые создают превьюшки на лету по запросу

Comment: Необязательно хранить все 10, но 1-2 придется точно.